# paragraph reflow and advance to next para?

Tags: fill-paragraph

Excuse tyro question (google hasn't helped), but the default behaviour of paragraph reflow (`M-q`) not advancing to the next para doesn't suit me, particularly when reflowing a large section of text, and i end up doing the combination para-reflow, advance para (`M-q`, `M-]`).   This is a surprising awkward combination to key in repeatedly.  Is there any simple way ("simple" is important for me!) to redefine `M-q` to behave like `M-q M-]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your init file (~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el on linux systems):

```
 (defun fill-paragraph-next ()
    (interactive)
    (fill-paragraph)
    (forward-paragraph))

 (define-key esc-map "q" 'fill-paragraph-next)
```

and restart emacs.

Comment: Brilliant!   *Exactly* what i was looking for!   Many thanks, Nick

Comment: In that case, please accept the answer.